# How to make one WCF service to be client of another WCF service?

Tags: wcf, service, client, web

I'm not experienced WCF programmer, so I do not fully understand all those configs and endpoints.
I have made two WCF services. One is web service hosted in IIS7, and the other is Windows service.
What should i change in which app.config and web.config to make possible to IIS7 service be a client of  Windows service. I have generated proxy for Win service imported in Web service, but I have no idea what to do with those app.config files... Can somebody give me general or concrete suggestions?

Thank you very much,
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

A simple general suggestion. You can start with:

```
Client1 => Service1
Client2 => Service2
```

Once that working you can take the configuration from `Client2` and copy it to `Service1`. Lastly you look at you `Service1` as a client and do the same stuff you did for `Client2` - add a service reference to `Service2` (or get the proxy through another way if you will). Effectively, now your `Service1` is also a `Client2`.

```
Client1 => Service1 => Client2 => Service2
```

WCF hosting doesn't matter here as services are communicating via ABC that is:

- A - address (e.g. http://localhost:8080/Service1)
- B - binding (e.g. BasicHttpBinding)
- C - contract (e.g. IService1 interface)